# Chrome Email Input Field built-in validation warning visually offset

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I'm building a super-simple sign-up form for a mini app and thought it'd be fun to use the browser's built-in HTML5 validations if I could - so I made the text input for the form a `type="email"` for funsies. Load it up in Chrome (27.0.1453.116) and attempted to enter an invalid email ("lksjdf" or something, you know), and as expected an error message pops up when I attempt to submit. But the unexpected part was the validation message is offset from the text box by about 60 pixels (give or take a few)(note that the email field is active, but the error message appears to point to the password field):

[image: screenshot of strange validation error]

If I remove all styling and just leave the markup, the validation message position is improved, but about the amount of margin and padding that were on the form field:

[image: second screenshot]

When I repeat the process in Firefox, the validations show up correctly.

As we're narrowing down the issue, it appears that having an `<h1>` tag just before the form tag causes the problem to appear - if I remove the `<h1>` tag then the validation message lines up correctly.

Is this a bug in Chrome? Is there a way I can force Chrome's validation messages to line up with the input correctly? Why would another tag cause it to not line up?

Here's the code so you can test/verify:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample App | Sign Up</title>
    <!-- stripped out styles and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- stripped out other irrelevant markup -->
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" id="new_user" method="post">
      <label for="user_name">Name</label>
      <input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text" />

      <label for="user_email">Email</label>
      <!-- This is the validation test field! -->
      <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" />

      <label for="user_password">Password</label>
      <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" />

      <label for="user_password_confirmation">Confirm Password</label>
      <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password" />

      <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create my account" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you reload the page before testing the hint ?

Comment: @e1che, yes. Also restarted Chrome to make sure I had the latest version. I've edited the question with my markup so you can repeat the test.

Comment: You should add your CSS as the HTML you provided doesn't exhibit the issue.

Comment: @j08691, oooh, I think we're narrowing down the issue then. My original markup has an `<h1>` tag just before the form tag. If you add that back to the markup, then the problem reappears. Will edit the question to add that tag back.